# Linq to XML, creating a new custom class for each distinct element of a certain form

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have a weird problem. I cannot modify the XML I need to work with in any way (which is causing me the problem). The XML I am dealing with takes the following form :

```
<DocumentRoot>
   <Parent>
      <ClassAttribute> Value </ClassAttribute>
      <ClassName> More Attributes </ClassName> <!--Can occur a varying number of times.-->
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <ClassAttribute> Value </ClassAttribute>
      <ClassName> More Attributes </ClassName>
      <ClassName> More Attributes </ClassName>
   </Parent>
</DocumentRoot>
```

What I wish to do is extract this information, and use it to instantiate a custom class, CustomClassName, which will then be added to a `List<CustomClassName>`, where each **distinct** `<ClassName>` element (not value) from the XML document is used to create a new CustomClassName of the following form :

```
public class CustomClassName {
   public string ClassName; //gotten from the ClassName element (NOT the value)
   public List<string> classAttributes //gotten from the value inside the ClassAttribute element
   public List<string> moreAttributes //gotten from the value inside the ClassName element

}
```

I hope I have explained my wishes clearly, if not please poke me for further information.

Is it possible to do this ?

Edit :

By each "distinct" ClassName element, I mean that the element ClassName will be present several times in the XML document, despite this I would like only one ClassName class to be instantiated with its relevant attributes (the value of the ClassAttribute element) and the value of the distinct ClassName element being "appended" to the end of the properties in instantiated class.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean (exactly) by "distinct element"? It would help if you could give some sample input XML and expected output.

Comment: In the `CustomClassName` class, it looks like the xml node `ClassName` is being referred to twice, once for the `ClassName` string property, then again as a `List<string>`... this just doesn't make sense given the logic you've provided. Also, *distinct element* of what?

Comment: just tell me whats the value of "ClassName" in the following example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
from n in doc.Root.Elements("Parent") select 
{
ClassName = n.Element("ClassName").First().Attribute("ATTRNAME").Value,
classAttributes = from a in n.Elements("ClassAttribute") select a.Value,
moreAttributes  = from a in n.Elements("ClassName") select a.Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(string)
List<CustomClassName> list = root.Descendants("ClassName").Select(x =>
new CustomClassName()
{
    ClassName = x.Name.LocalName, // is the name, not the value    
    classAttributes = x.Parent.Element("ClassAttribute").Value, // Value is a string, not a list, you'll have to do the conversion.
    moreAttributes = x.Value // is the value, but Value is a string, not a list, you'll have to do the conversion.
})
.ToList();
```

This doesn't make a whole lot of sense, why assign the string "ClassName" from the name of the `<ClassName>` element to the ClassName variable in the custom class.  But without more xml, its impossible to understand more than this.

I hope this helps you anyway.  The trick to this is the `Descendants("ClassName")` and then each node's `Parent.Element("ClassAttribute")` to get its attributes.